# Azure Function and Json.Net fails to deserialize large JSON in live environment

Tags: c#, json, azure, json.net, azure-functions

When I test my method that contains the logic of my function locally, it works. But when I run it in live environment I always get some error from

```
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json);
```

where `json` is a 7.5MB JSON file.

This time I'm getting

> Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: ". Path
>   'data.lcls.$values[1082].$type', line 66662, position 3618126

That line is just

```
"$type": "MyNamespaceOuter.MyNamespaceInner.MyType, MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Makes it frustrating to create reliable unit test coverage when simple lines of code that work locally aren't working in live env.

A few minutes ago I was getting an "unexpected end of file" when parsing the same blob, and it was pointing to a similar line (somewhere around line 67k).

Comment: Looks like something is truncating your file such that the JSON is incomplete.  Are you using a stream somewhere that isn't getting flushed?

Comment: @BrianRogers `json` is a string, so the values have been copied from the stream.

Comment: Right, but my point is you don't seem to be getting the complete JSON from the stream.   To rule out Json.Net, you could put a logging statement right before you try to deserialize the string: check whether it ends with `}` or `]`.  If it doesn't, you know you have incomplete JSON.  So then I would look at how you are reading the string from the stream-- are you closing it before everything is read?

Comment: @BrianRogers You're right. Something about my stream from Azure blob storage is not getting all the bytes … Thanks.